# Из-за чего в pattern не хватает места для фигуры

Tags: svg, svg-animation

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 400" width='1000' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='b'>
      <stop offset='20%' stop-color='green'></stop>
      <stop offset='40%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
      <stop offset='60%' stop-color='red'></stop>
      <stop offset='80%' stop-color='yellow'></stop>
      <stop offset='100%' stop-color='tomato'></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

        <defs>
          <pattern id="a" x='10' y='10' width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle r="15" cx="10" cy="10" fill="url(#b)" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
          </pattern>
        </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#a)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Если речь об обрезанном круге, то очевидно, что координата минус радиус `10 - 15 = -5` и круг вылезает за левую и верхнюю границы паттерна и закономерно обрезается

Comment: @andreymal понял спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представьте, что паттерн это одна кафельная плитка, которую вы будете укладывать на стенку определенных размеров.  Теория [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875) и [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/pattern)
В вашем примере, квадрат (стенка) имеет размеры `200 х 200 px`, следовательно при размере
`40 x 40 px` паттерна (одной плитки),  войдет 5 плиток по ширине и 5 рядов по высоте.

Всё, что находится внутри паттерна, опять же по аналогии с кафельной плиткой, является её узором и, что выходит за пределы границ плитки будет обрезано.

Чтобы облегчить расчеты положения центра окружности и её радиуса, располагайте её по центру паттерна.

```
<pattern id="a" x='0' y='0' width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20" fill="url(#b)" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
</pattern>
```

Я выбрал радиус `18px`, а не `20px`, чтобы обеспечить зазор `1px` по краям.

**Одна плитка**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='b'>
      <stop offset='20%' stop-color='green'></stop>
      <stop offset='40%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
      <stop offset='60%' stop-color='red'></stop>
      <stop offset='80%' stop-color='yellow'></stop>
      <stop offset='100%' stop-color='tomato'></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

        <defs>
          <pattern id="a" x='0' y='0' width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20" fill="url(#b)" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
          </pattern>
        </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" fill="url(#a)" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5px"/>
</svg>
```

**Пример многократного размещения паттерна  в квадрате 200 x 200px**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='b'>
      <stop offset='20%' stop-color='green'></stop>
      <stop offset='40%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
      <stop offset='60%' stop-color='red'></stop>
      <stop offset='80%' stop-color='yellow'></stop>
      <stop offset='100%' stop-color='tomato'></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

        <defs>
          <pattern id="a" x='0' y='0' width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20" fill="url(#b)" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
          </pattern>
        </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#a)" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

**Пример с радиусом (как в вопросе) `15px`**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" width='400' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='b'>
      <stop offset='20%' stop-color='green'></stop>
      <stop offset='40%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
      <stop offset='60%' stop-color='red'></stop>
      <stop offset='80%' stop-color='yellow'></stop>
      <stop offset='100%' stop-color='tomato'></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

        <defs>
          <pattern id="a" x='0' y='0' width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle r="15" cx="20" cy="20" fill="url(#b)" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
          </pattern>
        </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#a)" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

### Примеры анимации паттерна

Используется точечный паттерн и анимация маски

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <defs>

            <pattern
                    id="dotted-pattern"
                    viewbox="0,0,100,100"
                    height="3.125%"
                    width="3.125%">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="#10446D" r="12"/>
                    
            </pattern>
            <mask id="circle-mask" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <circle id="kk" cx="50" cy="50" r="38.48" width="100" height="100" fill="white">
            <animate
                        attributeName="r"
                        values="0.01; 38.48"
                        dur="3s"
                        begin="0s"
                        repeatCount="1"
                        fill="freeze" />
          </circle>
            </mask>
        </defs>
    
        <rect
                width="74"
                height="74"
                y="13"
                x="13"
                mask="url(#circle-mask)"
                fill="url(#dotted-pattern)"></rect>
        
        
    </svg>
```

Используется SMIL анимация вращения и изменения цвета

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="350">
<defs>
<pattern id="motif" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" overflow="visible" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" style="stroke:yellow;stroke-width:1;fill:yellow"/>
<circle cx="22" cy="15" r="7" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1;fill:green">
<animateTransform begin="GO.click" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0,15,15;360,15,15" repeatCount="2" dur="2s"/>
<animate begin="GO.click" attributeName="fill" values="green;red;green" repeatCount="2" dur="2s"/>
</circle>
</pattern>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" fill="url(#motif)"/>
<rect id="GO" x="210" y="330" width="50" height="18" opacity="0.3"/>
<text x="235" y="345" text-anchor="middle" font-size="15" fill="white" pointer-events="none">GO</text>
</svg>
```

Более сложная, комплексная анимация паттерна

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="350">
<defs>
<pattern id="motif" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" overflow="visible" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<animate begin="GO.click" attributeName="width" values="30;8;30" repeatCount="1" dur="4s"/>
<animate begin="GO.click" attributeName="height" values="30;8;30" repeatCount="1" dur="4s"/>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1;fill:yellow">
<animate begin="GO.click" attributeName="width" values="30;8;30" repeatCount="1" dur="4s"/>
<animate begin="GO.click" attributeName="height" values="30;8;30" repeatCount="1" dur="4s"/>
</rect>
<circle cx="15" cy="15" r="13" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1;fill:green">
<animate begin="GO.click" attributeName="r" values="13;2;13" repeatCount="1" dur="4s"/>
<animate begin="GO.click" attributeName="cx" values="15;4;15" repeatCount="1" dur="4s"/>
<animate begin="GO.click" attributeName="cy" values="15;4;15" repeatCount="1" dur="4s"/>
</circle>
</pattern>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" fill="url(#motif)"/>
<rect id="GO" x="210" y="330" width="50" height="18" fill="black"/>
<text x="235" y="345" text-anchor="middle" font-size="15" fill="white" pointer-events="none">GO</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: здесь https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875 говорится что pattern должен быть в defs а тут нет https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1063/210/lecture/5432?page=5#sect5 как правильно ?

Comment: @Leks можно и так и так, но чаще pattern, как и gradient, mask правильнее размещать в `<defs>`

Comment: ок Вас понял ...

Comment: В чем разница между patternUnits и patternContentUnits ?